# Send http.patch request on server in Nativescript application

Tags: http, angular, typescript, patch, nativescript

I'm trying to send http.patch request on server in Nativescrpt(Typescript + Angular2) application. Backend is written on Python(Django)

It's my request

```
  updateOrder(id, message) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Token " + Config.token);
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return this.http.patch(
      Config.apiUrl + "orders/" + id + "/",
      message,
      {headers: headers}
  )
  .map(response => response.json())
  .catch((res: Response) => this.handleErrors(res));
```

And here I send it.

```
changeStatus(status){
    var message = JSON.stringify({status: status});
    this.orderService.updateOrder(this.order.id, message).subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        err => alert(JSON.stringify(err))
    );
}
```

But server returns such data:

```
{"_body":{},"status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}
```

And my property "status", that i want to change, remains the same.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: _"And my property "status", that i want to change, remains the same."_ - Isn't this something that you should be doing on the server side? If that's not your question, can you clarify a bit what the problem is. It's not very clear at this point

Comment: There is a method on a server side, which should process this query, but my problem is that it seems like query isn't sending, cause there's no changes in my data.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on the server side?

Comment: I made debug point, but my query ignored that. As I understand the query didn't reached the server. And I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **http** module from NativeScript.

Sending PATCH should look  similar to the example below:

page.ts (TypeScript example)

```
  import * as http from"http";
  http.request({
      url: "https://httpbin.org/patch",
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      content: JSON.stringify({ MyVariableOne: "ValueOne", MyVariableTwo: "ValueTwo" })
  }).then(response => {
      var result = response.content.toJSON();
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

API reference for HTTP module : [https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/*http*.html](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_http_.html)

Documentation article here: https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http#post-json

Comment: I tried made it, but in that case I've got the next error: error TS2345: Argument of type '{ url: string; method: string; headers: Headers; content: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Request'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'content' does not exist in type 'string | Request'.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when I need to make http requests:

1.- Import the  NativeScript http module in the Root App NgModule:

```
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ...
      NativeScriptHttpModule,
      ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

2.- Import Angular http (and headers if needed) to component:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

3.- Inject it in the constructor:

```
constructor(private http: Http, ...) { ... }
```

4.- Use the http methods (i.e. POST here, but works with any):

```
var url = "http://www.api-url.com/example.php";
var body = {foo: "foo", bar:"bar"};
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", token); //You can append any header you need
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.connectionEstablished(data),
        err => this.handleErrors(err)
    );
```

If you get any error with the method *map()* you need to add this line:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
```

Hope it helps!